# Replacing fragment in ViewPager after selecting option in Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

As many applications I have MainActivity with ViewPager.
When I select option in NavigationDrawer I want to change one fragment in ViewPager. So to achieve that I created something like this:

Option click listener:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int pos) {
        mainActivity.changeFragment(pos);
    }
```

MainActivity method:

```
public void changeFragment(final int key) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mainPagerAdapter.setKey(key);
            }
        });
    }
```

And MainPagerAdapter:

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public final static int NUM_OF_PAGES = 2;

    private int mCurrentFragmentKey = 0;

    public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == HOME) {
            if (mCurrentFragmentKey == 0) 
                return new Fragment1();
            else
                return new Fragment2();
        } else
            return new SecondViewPagerFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_OF_PAGES;
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        mCurrentFragmentKey = key;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**Question:**

Unfortunately it's not working properly because when I select option whole view stutters giving bad performance. How can I fix that?

**Edit**

I changed notifying pager that data set changed into this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainPagerAdapter.setKey(key);
                }
            }, 500);
```

And now everything works fine, but I'm not sure that is best solution. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

What about if you have various adapter that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter and when you need to change the contents in the viewpager, you simple call `pager.setAdapter(anotherAdapter)`?

If setAdapter supply the views to be shown, changing the adapter probably will make the content of your viewpager change.

Comment: How it would work if I wanted to get back by back button ?

Comment: You could do the same thing as the app of gmail does, you could have a default adapter, so if you press the back button, you set this default adapter to your viewpager, if you are already on this default adapter, just call super.onBackPressed for the default behaviour (quit from the app), otherwise you will need a Linked List to create a "historic stack", so when you press the back button you just need to pop this stack. This Linked List could be a list of FragmentStatePagerAdapter, you'll just need to add your adapter that you passed to setAdapter everytime you call your changeFragment().

Comment: I thought about the same idea with fragment on the stack, so when I get to my computer I will check your solution

Comment: I don't know if there is another way of doing it, I believe not, maybe you'll have to implement your own stack. Fine, if it does not work, I'll get my pc too and check if I can help you with another solution.